# Filter Values in ChangeContentType Control

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

I am using the SharePoint:ChangeContentType control (which renders as a DropDownList in New/Edit modes). I need to manipulate the values that are present in the rendered DropDownList in the CodeBehind. I can't manipulate them with JavaScript/jQuery because I will get a ViewState exception.

I can get a reference to the ChangeContentType control but can't cast it as a DropDownList and therefore I can't get a refernce to the items in it in order to add/remove stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How to find `ContentTypeChoice` control ([DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) in [SharePoint:ChangeContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.changecontenttype.aspx) control:

```
DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList) control.TemplateContainer.FindControl("ContentTypeChoice");
```

`ContentTypeChoice` control gets populated during page load event.